# How to solve HTTP Status 404

Tags: java, jsp, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to write a simple web app in JSP that allows user to choose 2 numbers in the range 1-100 from 2 drop-down lists and then print out those numbers. However, I keep receiving the error message:

[image]

Below is my code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Game Table</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="post">
        #rows: 
        <select name="row">
            <%
                for(int i=1;i<=100;i++){
                    out.println("<option value="+"\""+i+"\""+">"+i+"</option>");
                 }
            %> 


        </select>
        #columns:
        <select name="column">
            <%
                for(int i=1;i<=100;i++){
                    out.println("<option value="+"\""+i+"\""+">"+i+"</option>");
                 }
            %> 

    </form> 

    <%
        String row=request.getParameter("row");
        String column=request.getParameter("column");
        if(row!=null && column!=null){
            out.println(row+" "+column);
        }
    %>
</body>
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

well, problem is in navigation not in your code. For not showing dropdown menu so use proper url mapping to run your jsp like `http://localhost:8080/yourwebprojectname/game.jsp` `game.jsp` is assumption of your following above code page name.

Your code have many error like missing of `action=""` like

```
<form method="post" action="book.jsp">
```

`</Select>` tag above the form

Main problem is you dont have any button or use of ajax to show the output that you trying to display via `Scriptlet`

for simple solution add a button inside your form

```
<input type="submit" value="show" name="show"/>
```

add code something like this inside your Scriptlet

```
if("show".equals(request.getParameter("show"))){
    if(row!=null && column!=null){
        out.println(row+" "+column);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not completely sure, but it might be returning 404 (not found) because you are not submitting this data correctly. See, there is no "action" atribute indicating where it should go (e.g. "save.jsp").

Hope it helps! :)